# Why does my function that replaces a certain character only do this to the first instance of the character?

Tags: c, function

I  have this function:

```
char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
 static char buffer[4096];
 char *p;

 if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))
    return str;

 strncpy(buffer, str, p-str);
 buffer[p-str] = '\0';

 sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));

 return buffer;
}
```

When I use it, it only changes the first instance of the character to be replaced. Is there any way i can make it get it to do this to all said characters?

Comment: Yes. Repeat replacing until all of what should be replaced are replaced.

Comment: Lol. Just noticed how redundant i was.. Thank you ;)

Comment: Note that this approach only works if  `rep` is not longer than `orig`.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a loop that reallocates the beginning of the string after the ending of your replacement string. Indeed, your function performs the action only once, since strstr returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the word orig in str.

EDIT: This may give you an idea of how to do it. I can't test it on this computer, so it might not work directly.
I did it using malloc, since static char shouldn't be used this way, in my opinion. It is supposed to store the values in buffer *for a future use of the function.* If you re-use this function, you would lose the previous return value of the function...
This is my way of doing it, there is certainly a more efficient way of doing it. The advantage of this function is that it adapts to any string length.

```
char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{      
  char *buffer;
  char *previous_version;
  char *p;
  size_t occurring_position;

  if (strcmp(orig, rep) == 0)
  {  
     return(str); 
  }         
  buffer = strdup(str);
  while ((p = strstr(buffer, orig)))
  {
     occuring_position = p - buffer;
     previous_version = strdup(buffer);
     free(buffer);
     buffer = malloc(strlen(previous_version) + strlen(rep) - strlen(orig)); 
     strcnpy(buffer, previous_version, occurring_position);
     strcpy(buffer, rep);
     strcpy(buffer + occurring_position + strlen(rep), previous_version + occurring_position + strlen(orig));
     free(previous_version);
  }
  return (buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure if i implemented it correctly. Where do I put the While ? It's totally deleting my string i think.

Comment: @Damien What is "buffer"? Where does 4096 come from?  Ah - now I see it in the original code, but not in your answer.